# Write a LWRP that invokes another resource notifies method

Tags: resources, chef-infra

I'm trying to write a LWRP that extends the Execute resource.
I'd like the `notifies` attribute/method in my LWRP to pass through to the `notifies` methods of the Execute resource

In the resource I have:

```
attribute :notifies,     :kind_of => Array,  :default => []
```

In the provider I have

```
execute something do
  ...
  r.notifies.empty? ? nil : notifies(*r.notifies)
end
```

In return get an arguments error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)
```

Appreciate any hints or tips.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that `:notifies` attribute exists in **any** LWRP, as it is provided by the base class. So you should not add this attribute to resource file.

And you can use just the assigment in provider, no need to check for nil.

```
execute something do
  ...
  notifies r.notifies
end
```